# Scheme # void error

Tags: scheme, void

I tried running the following scheme code:

```
(define affiche-gagnant 
  (lambda (j1 j2 g1 g2)
    (begin 
      (display "Le gagnant est : ")
      (display 
       (cond ((> g1 g2) j1) 
             ((< g1 g2) j2) 
             (else (begin (display "personne. ") (display j1) (display " et ") (display j2) (display " sont exaequos. "))))))))
```

But I get the following output:

```
Le gagnant est : personne. Alper et Ezgi sont exaequos. #<void>
```

Where did the `#void` come from? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Show us how the call is made, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, wrong answer. You have an extra display:

```
(define affiche-gagnant 
  (lambda (j1 j2 g1 g2)
    (begin 
      (display "Le gagnant est : ")
       (cond ((> g1 g2) (display j1)) 
             ((< g1 g2) (display j2)) 
             (else (begin (display "personne. ") (display j1) (display " et ") (display j2) (display " sont exaequos. ")))))))
```

Should work.

Comment: could u add ur answer to my function ??
(affiche-gagnant "Alper" "Ezgi" 1 1)

Comment: Your function is correct. It's the way you call it that's wrong. What are you using? DrScheme? DrRacket? Tell me what you type in the prompt to test your function.

Comment: it's drscheme
no, i called the fuction:  (affiche-gagnant "Alper" "Ezgi" 1 1)

Comment: Glad your first experience with SO was successful. :D

Comment: if ALPER win your function gives me 
Le gagnant est : 
I don't see who win the game

Answer (score 0):

In some implementations of Scheme, any function that shouldn't return anything (such as begin, define, set!) actually returns a special value `#<void>`. It is an error to display such a value. In your case, it was an extra "display".

```
(define affiche-gagnant 
  (lambda (j1 j2 g1 g2)
    (begin 
      (display "Le gagnant est : ")
      (cond
        ((> g1 g2) j1) 
        ((< g1 g2) j2) 
        (else (begin (display "personne. ") (display j1) (display " et ") (display j2) (display " sont exaequos. ")))))))
```