# Scheme function error

Tags: scheme, void

```
(define affiche-gagnant
  (lambda (j1 j2 g1 g2)

(begin 

  (display "Le gagnant est : ")

   (cond ((> g1 g2) j1) 

         ((< g1 g2) j2)

         (else (begin (display "personne. ") (display j1) (display " et ") (display j2) (display " sont exaequos. ")))))))
```

When j1 or j2 win the game it says :

```
 Le gagnant est :

    We don't see who win the game :(
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The subject and question seems like 2 different things. Please try give more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheme # void error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434638/scheme-void-error)

Comment: He had a different problem and I solved it for him, but this new one is edited into that question. So, duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheme # void error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434638/scheme-void-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered this already.

```
(define affiche-gagnant
  (lambda (j1 j2 g1 g2)

(begin 

  (display "Le gagnant est : ")

   (cond ((> g1 g2) (display j1)) ; You're returning, not displaying

         ((< g1 g2) (display j2)) 

         (else (begin (display "personne. ") (display j1) (display " et ") (display j2) (display " sont exaequos. ")))))))
```